# Python 3.6.3 dictionary issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a problem when working on jupyter notebook using python 3.6.3.
when I write following code in one cell and execute:

```
x=dict()
y=dict()
for j in range(3):
    x[j]=str(j)
y=x
for i in range(2):
    y[i]=5
```

This will give me the result that both x and y being the same as {0:5,1:5,2:'2'}, which is weird to me since I expect x={0: '0', 1: '1', 2: '2'} and y = {0: 5, 1: 5, 2: '2'}.
I don't understand why the above code will change x as well while I assign new values to y
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [quick guide to what assignment actually does in Python](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: your 5th line says is all: "y it x". After that anything you do to `y` will also be done to `x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 5 you make y point to the exact same dictionary as x, so they are no longer two separate dicts. So what ever you will assign to x will be assigned to y and vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks, Will this property only affect dictionary or some other data structure in Python?

Comment: All mutable types behave similarly.  You can look up this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8056598/5751251. Basically lists, sets, dicts and bytearrays are mutable.